# Sorting a list with objects?

Tags: java, sorting

In the contacts class (implements actionListener) I have a JList that contains objects (elements from a file). There are sorting buttons, each button has an actionListener 
**by firstname 
by last name 
by city** 
 The sorting is done by the elements of objects.

the user should give the first and last name and city for a contact. How to do the sorting ??

And to put those into the list I used this code:

```
Map<String, contacts> ma = readFromFile();
for (Map.Entry<String, contacts> entry : ma.entrySet()) {
    contacts c = (contacts) entry.getValue();
    d.addElement(c.getLastName() + "" + c.getFirstName() + "" + c.getCity());
}
```

How to do the sorting ?? plz help

Comment: This is C++? Please update your tags.

Comment: What language is it? You usually use Sort function/method provided by the language or its library, so you must say what technology you use.

Comment: @Barmar - looks like java

Comment: Yeah, probably Java.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `JList<String>`, create a `JList<contacts>`

Implement class ContactsRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer.
See java doc for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html

Implement your custom list data model:

```
public class ContactsModel extends AbstractListModel<contacts>() {

    private final List<contacts> backingList = ArrayList<contacts>;

    public ContactsModel(Map<String, contacts> ma) {
        //populate backing list here from your map
    }

    public int getSize() { 
        return backingList.size(); 
    }

    public contacts getElementAt(int index) { 
        return backingList.get(index); 
    }
};
```

Add a sort method to your model:

```
public void sort(Comparator<contacts> comparator) {
    Collections.sort(backingList, comparator);
    fireContentsChanged(this, 0, backingList.size());
}
```

Implement comparators for every sort use case:

```
public class LastNameAscendingComparator implements Comparator<contacts> {

    @Override
    public int compare(contacts c1, contacts c2){
        return c1.getLastName().compareTo(c2.getLastName());
    }
}
```

Finally call your model.sort() with a corresponding comparator

Comment: what if I'm using DefaultListModel ?

Answer (score 0):

In java you can sort a list like so:

```
Collections.sort(yourListOfContacts, new Comparator<Contacts>(){

    @Override
    public int compare(Contacts obj1, Contacts obj2){
       obj1.getFirstName().compareTo(obj2.getFirstName());
    }

});
```

Notice that the return type of the compare function is an integer. This integer tells the sorting algorithm which one of the two should come first. Note that a `-1` means the first element is "less" than the second, a `0` means that they are the same, and a `1` means that the first element is "greater" than the second. So, to reverse the order, you would use: `obj2.getFirstName().compareTo(obj1.getFirstName());` or, you could just multiply by `-1`.

The other fields you want to sort by will follow the same sort of pattern, this is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

In Java8 you can sort a list like this:

```
Collections.sort(contactList, (contact1, contact2) 
    -> contact1.getName().compareTo(contact2.getName()));
```